# Printer-friendly layout truncates long titles on Firefox

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, firefox, printing

When I print a stackoverflow question from Firefox that has a long title, the title is truncated.  The rest of the layout looks fine.

[Here is a sample SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219693/can-a-c-dll-compiled-using-visual-studio-2008-be-used-with-visual-studio-2005).

On my printer, the title is truncated at the 'a' in the second 'Visual Studio'.  I'm using Firefox 3.0.13 on 32-bit Vista.

Comment: I also lose a lot of the pretty-formatted code in questions where the code would go beyond the edge of the page -- I know it's not *easy* to wrap things in such a way as to make intentional versus word-wrap-caused line breaks visually distinct, but I think it's important that it *work*

Answer (score 5):

You can now use StackPrinter to better format questions for printing; it was built using the API:

[StackApps - StackPrinter: The Stack Exchange Printer Suite](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite)

Comment: So that's why StackPrinter got so many upvotes... nothing wrong with that, of course - it's awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Page Setup, and check "Shrink to fit Page Width". Should take care of it...

---

**Edit:** Reproduced in IE8 as well, if you change the default scaling from "Shrink to fit" to 100%.

Comment: But for a long title, wouldn't that make the main text really small?  I think a better solution is for the title to wrap.

Comment: I think a better solution is to not print the internet.

Comment: Web browsers can print and so you might think that someone would want to print out a stackoverflow question.  Instead of saying "don't click that button" it's usually a better design decision to make things work as intended.

Comment: *Shrink to fit* does not solve it. I tested it. For what reason soever... (But manually adjusting the size works.)

Comment: It'll wrap. You can test with this page. Prints great on FF 3.5... If it's still not working for you, then I suggest you upgrade your browser!

Comment: I tested it with 3.5.2 ;)

Comment: As did I. Ok, here's a full list of my settings: Portrait, Shrink to fit, all margins set to .2", no headers or footers, 8.5" x 11" paper.

Comment: I think you are missing the point.  Printing should fundamentally work right out of the box without messing with any settings.

Comment: Ok, it's an issue with the margins. Below 15mm it fits, above not.

Comment: **@John:** Verified. This ("shrink to fit" not working) would appear to be a bug in Firefox. **@Dana:** I'm not suggesting this couldn't or shouldn't be fixed in SO's stylesheet, but if you actually need to print then I don't know why you're arguing against a work-around built into the browser for just this situation.

Comment: @Dana Robinson: Remember that printing is buggy/inconsistent across almost all browsers.

Comment: Oh, I don't care about it for me, personally.  I just had to print a question out for a meeting where there was no network access so I don't care about the truncation for my own purposes.  I just wanted to point it out since it should be able to work fine with modern browsers with a CSS tweak.

Answer (score -3):

The real question here is:

> Why on earth would you print a StackOverflow question to begin with?

Comment: Do you mean to say that you read SO questions on your *screen*?

Comment: @Shog9: No way! I have a machine that reads my screen with a camera and then chistles it in stone where I can then read it comfortably.

Comment: I hate trees and plants in general.  This is also why I'm a vegetarian.

Comment: Ahhh, a vegetarian. This makes sense now.

Comment: He runs a paperless office - *because he eats all the paper!*