# Printer-Friendly Button

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, printing

Details of printing have been talked about, but this is the feature request for a Printer-Friendly Button.  The button would print a good-looking version of the question and answers instead of just using the print feature of your browser. It would allow just the Q&A to be printed and not other additional items. There could even be a user setting or some way to print with comments also.

Comment: Poor trees.. :(

Comment: You still print stuff???

Comment: By "Pretty Print", I *think* from the context you mean a printer-friendly view; is that right? "Pretty Print" *usually* means a code formatter / painter (which is *mostly* there already).

Comment: @Marc, yes I meant a printer-friendly view like I get for my CC and bank statements, sorry if I got the terminology wrong.

Comment: I would like a Printer Friendly button.

Comment: @AndreasBonini-Poor trees because there is no printer friendly button. You print 3 times more pages (including ads) without that button!

Comment: Anyone know how to turn this off

Comment: @TiagoLiraDosSantos, they never implemented it, so there is nothing to turn off.

Answer (score 10):

There's not really any need for a button, if a style sheet for printing is defined (with `media="print"` attribute).  Those ["Click here for printer-friendly version" links are generally considered a bad idea](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/).

<del>Stack Overflow currently does not define a print stylesheet. I think you'd have a slightly better chance of getting your suggestion approved if you changed your question to something like "please provide a style sheet for printing."</del>

<del>Of course, I'm pretty sure the response would be something like "this is already a very text-heavy website, I don't think it's needed." :)</del>

**Edit**: I was wrong, printer styles *are* defined. They are in the same stylesheet, using `@media print`.

Comment: Look in the stylesheet for `@media print` - There's your print version.

Comment: @random thanks, didn't check there

Comment: +1 because printer-friendly versions are evil.

Comment: OK but AFAIK the "print media" stylesheet isn't that *good* -- I'm losing parts of text blocks and the code is just a mess, for example here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875467/java-client-certificates-over-https-ssl

even with "shrink to fit", in Firefox 3.X.  Maybe the CSS still needs work then?

Comment: gmail has printer-friendly button.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if there's a big need to support printing, but in truth, when you want to print something, it should come out of the printer in a way that's better formatted for printed media. The print stylesheet does a decent job by itself, but there are some things I find lacking.

It would be nice to have a "printable view" of a question that does/has the following:

- Shows the question, and all answers on a single (web) page. Currently it's question + each page of answers (by design), so you end up with multiple printed copies of a question. This wastes paper, is confusing, and also makes it somewhat annoying if you want to print only certain sections of the answers.
- Shows the vote count for answers
- Hides all functional links such as "add comment", etc. Currently, this is partly implemented.
- Shows the entire comment history on all answers. Currently you'd have to expand all the answer comment histories manually.
- Hides the page footer.
- Various layout tweaks to reduce the printed length. For example, comments currently have way too much empty vertical space.

---

**UPDATE:** There is now an API-based application called [StackPrinter](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stackoverflow-trilogy-printer-suite), as Jeff pointed out [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19356/printer-friendly-layout-truncates-long-titles-on-firefox/50871#50871) -- I haven't tried it myself, but it should solve some of the issues I've mentioned here.

Comment: Actually i quoted you in the app description, so the circle is closed :). http://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stackoverflow-trilogy-printer-suite

Answer (score 3):

I like that there are print-styles defined; I'd like to see Stack overflow use media selectors to make the printed result appear like a printed document, rather than a printed website.

The extra time and effort involved would allow me to put some of my most-important answers on my wall, or in a notebook and make the best use of the paper, etc.