# Stop partial topbar and uneeded footer information from printing

Tags: feature-request, printing

Currently if you use the browser print feature to print a Q&A page, you get stuff in the topbar printing, though not all of it.  I don't think any of it normally needs to be printed, so could we remove that from the print-style.

A second point would be the footer comment that prints currently (starting "Not the answer you're looking for?..."), which is not normally needed in a print.

**Here's a snapshot of the header:**

[image: Print Header]

**And here's a snapshot of the footer:**

[image: Print Footer]

Comment: Related: [Print Button Request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36709/printer-friendly-button)

Comment: Does this issue happen if you use [StackPrinter](http://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite)?

Comment: @GraceNote, nope, those elements aren't printed in StackPrinter.

Comment: Looks like this has been fixed, presumably as a side effect of deploying the new top bar.

Answer (score 1):

We don't natively offer a printer-friendly copy on our system. However, there is [StackPrinter](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite) available for printing full question pages (and 2nd place winner of our [API contest back in 2010](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/stack-exchange-api-contest-winners/)), and [Print this Post](https://stackapps.com/questions/3307/print-this-post) available for singular posts, which offer printer-friendly systems to the network.

We do not have any current plans to implement this sort of thing directly into the system, so implementing fixes to the printer copy of our site when there's a better solution via existing tools is equally unlikely.

Comment: I think you put this on the wrong post, this is more for my Print Button Request post.  All I'm asking you to do here is change the print style that you have already implemented, as per this [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36734/13295)

Comment: @Lance We're not likely to change things here, either, especially since I confirmed that the issue isn't an issue in StackPrinter in the comments. I s'pose that wasn't entirely clear in my answer though, so I'll address that.

Comment: Well, that seems pretty lazy and wierd, since they have a printer stylesheet that they already implemented, they just didn't fix it when they implemented the new topbar, so all those out there who don't know about the specialized application will now be printing out extra useless stuff.  I'll never understand that kind of apathy, especially now that there's 26.9 million visitors/month; how many of them do you think have come to Meta or StackApps and figured out they could use StackPrinter?  "Print" doesn't even show in the help Center.