# Bring back the <10k trick for viewing a deleted question

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, deleted-questions, 10k-tools

For anyone unaware, for a long time now, you've been able to change a URL from `/questions/12345/some-title-here` to `/posts/12345/edit` to be able to see a deleted question, [without the required 10k reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174811/howto-view-deleted-posts-10k-rep).

It seems since the [Users without full edit rights should not be able to submit edits to deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181813/users-without-full-edit-rights-should-not-be-able-to-submit-edits-to-deleted-pos) bug was fixed, the entire page can no longer be viewed (not only unsubmittable).

Please, for the sake of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73455/popular-deleted-so-su-programmers-questions-list, bring back this neat little hack, with the submit button disabled.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-declined] in 3... 2... 1...

Comment: You realize that was a bug, right? [Please bring back spacebar heating!](http://xkcd.com/1172/)

Comment: Downvotes? I really expected people to want it back...

Comment: @EmrakultheAeonsTorn there's always a relevant XKCD, isn't there?

Comment: I'm sure a lot of users do want it back, but it kind of defeats the  point of reputation to see deleted posts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, since this was [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), here's an alternative:

```
http://www.stackprinter.com/export?service=stackoverflow&printer=false&question=x
```

Where `x` is a question ID. So for [What's your favorite "programmer" cartoon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556):

http://www.stackprinter.com/export?service=stackoverflow&printer=false&question=84556

Comment: What is this 'stackprinter'? I've never heard of it before - is it a service run by SE, or an external service?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII It's external, built using the API, as pointed out by Jeff here: [Printer-friendly layout truncates long titles on Firefox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/50871)

Comment: Who needs a trick based on a bug (it was pretty limited anyway), when we have *this!?*

Comment: @brasofilo The URL change for the bug was very easy to remember. *That* URL... not so much. Oh well, I guess it will drive me to get 10k rep on SO and MSO.

Comment: I spoke too early, it didn't "print" a couple of deleted Q's I tried with :/

Comment: @brasofilo Yeah I read somewhere that it was a "partial" archive. What I'm wondering is if it's going to break soon, given the bug fix, seeing as it apparently uses the API... Still, it [kinda] works.

Comment: @Danny StackPrinter is hosted on App Engine for free which limit the Datastore size quota to 1 GB; so I just keep questions above 15 upvotes that are printed on StackPrinter at least one time before the deletion on SE.

Comment: Doesn't show deleted questions.

Answer (score 19):

If we're going to reintroduce this particular behaviour, we might as well just show deleted questions to everybody. Except that then they wouldn't be deleted.